# Replace with the extract in multiple substrings in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, regex

I have the next string:

```
## This is h2
Paragraph text

### This is h3
#### This is h4
```

and I want this:

```
<h2>This is h2</h2>
Paragraph text

<h3>This is h2</h3>
<h4>This is h2</h4>
```

How could I do it?

With Regex is easy to find the sentence, but I don't know how to replace it with the extracting sentence and from multiple matchs in the string.

```
##.*
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` with `lambda`:

```py
import re

s = """\
## This is h2
Paragraph text

### This is h3
#### This is h4"""

s = re.sub(
    r"^(#+)\s+(.*)",
    lambda g: "<h{h}>{s}</h{h}>".format(h=len(g.group(1)), s=g.group(2)),
    s,
    flags=re.M,
)

print(s)
```

Prints:

```html
<h2>This is h2</h2>
Paragraph text

<h3>This is h3</h3>
<h4>This is h4</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

One could do tedious substitutions like

- `re.sub(r'^####', '<h4>', line)`
- `re.sub(r'^###', '<h3>', line)`
- `re.sub(r'^##', '<h2>', line)`
- `re.sub(r'^#', '<h1>', line)`

but you're probably much better off with `m = re.search(r'^(#+)', line)`,
assign `n = len(m.group(1))`,
and synthesize `f'<h{n}>'` from that.

You can close with e.g. `</h4>` if you like,
or perhaps you'd prefer to let /usr/bin/tidy
or bs4 `soup.prettify()` attend to those details.